# Saving a Log Object to sqllite no id only one record gets inserted?

Tags: c#, sqlite, ormlite-servicestack

```html
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.OrmLite;

public static string SqliteFileDb = "~/App_Data/db.sqlite".MapHostAbsolutePath();

private static void CreateX(Message msg)
{
//Using Sqlite DB- improved
 var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(SqliteFileDb, SqliteDialect.Provider);
// Wrap all code in using statement to not forget about using db.Close()
using (var db = dbFactory.Open())
{
db.CreateTableIfNotExists<Message>();                    
Message notex = new Message();
notex.Content = msg.Content;
notex.Datestamp = msg.Datestamp;
notex.Facility = msg.Facility;
notex.Hostname = msg.Hostname;
notex.LocalDate = msg.LocalDate;
notex.RemoteIP = msg.RemoteIP;
notex.Severity = msg.Severity;
db.Save(notex))                  
db.Close();              
}
}

 public class Message
{
        public FacilityType Facility { get; set; }
        public SeverityType Severity { get; set; }
        public DateTime Datestamp { get; set; }
        public string Hostname { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string RemoteIP{ get; set; }
        public DateTime LocalDate { get; set; }
}
```

Can someone advice how to address this
case where I am saving a syslog message
to an sqlite db using servicestack orm.

Seems only one object is always available
and gets updated.Hence no new record getting
created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't provide a Primary Key in OrmLite, OrmLite will assume the primary key is the first property in the table which is not what you want in this case. You either need to tell OrmLite which property it should use for the Primary Key by annotating it with the `[PrimaryKey]` attribute, or just add an auto incrementing primary key which the database will populate itself, e.g:

```
public class Message
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public in Id { get; set; }
    public FacilityType Facility { get; set; }
    public SeverityType Severity { get; set; }
    public DateTime Datestamp { get; set; }
    public string Hostname { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string RemoteIP{ get; set; }
    public DateTime LocalDate { get; set; }
}
```

Also `db.Close()` is redundant in a using statement and there's no feature you want to use with OrmLite's high-level `Save()` API in this case so you should just have:

```
using (var db = dbFactory.Open())
{
    db.CreateTableIfNotExists<Message>();                    
    Message notex = new Message();
    notex.Content = msg.Content;
    notex.Datestamp = msg.Datestamp;
    notex.Facility = msg.Facility;
    notex.Hostname = msg.Hostname;
    notex.LocalDate = msg.LocalDate;
    notex.RemoteIP = msg.RemoteIP;
    notex.Severity = msg.Severity;
    db.Insert(notex);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had a though that this may have been the issue,but I was assuming the framework would take care of this kinda case.I will add an ID and try and mark this as answer.